# How to exclude the where condition from the native query when the parameter is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot v2.6.1 and Postgres DB for my application. I have the below method in one of my repositories.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from subscriptions s " +
            "WHERE (:merchantID is NULL OR s.created_by = cast(:merchantID AS text)) " +
            "AND (:status is NULL or s.status IN (:status))", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Subscription> findWithStatus (@Param("merchantID")String merchantID, @Param("status") List<String> status);
```

When the parameter 'status' is not null, it works fine. But when it is null it throws an exception

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea**

From this, I understand that the condition is not excluded from the query even though the specified parameter is null. I thought the problem is checking whether the parameter is null that is in **:status is null**, so I just changed the list parameter to **String** and passed a null value, still the same exception is thrown. So the problem is not with **:status is null** but with the IN operator in the query.

How to exclude this condition with IN operator when the parameter is null?

Comment: Provide two methods and let the caller decide.

Comment: To simply the problem statement I reduced the number of parameters and posted it here. Actually, I have three parameters with the List type. So I need to have more than two methods in that case which won't be good

Comment: "won't look good"? You actually provide a method called `findWithStatus` but you want to omit the status. That means the whole meaning of that method changes. So ... provide several methods! Having only one method that behaves differently ... that does not look good to me.

Comment: try to use ```s.status = ANY(:status)``` instead of ```s.status IN (:status)``` and it should work. If it works, I will write a more elaborated answer to state why it works :)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I would do that if the filter is only by status. My actual method is named findWithFilter and it has five parameters, out of five three are list types and out of five only one parameter is not null and the rest four can be null.

Comment: @motaa I changed to ANY operator but it did not work. It throws an exception ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side. So changed the parameter from List<String>  to String[] but no luck

Comment: Aight, what does ```:status``` look like in form of a string? I ask this because the IN-Operator is used on a comma separated set like ```IN (1,2,3,4,5,...)``` where as ANY-Operator works in a set like ```ANY('{1,2,3,4,5,...}')```

Comment: if its not null then it would look like Active, In-Active, Paused in the form of String

Comment: @Praveen if you pass a List of Strings, make sure that it translates to a form of ```IN('Active', 'In-Active', 'Paused')```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241423/discussion-between-praveen-and-motaa).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this Native Query approximation, one solution is adding an additional Boolean parameter that indicates if the Status List is null.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * from subscriptions s " +
            "WHERE (:merchantID is NULL OR s.created_by = cast(:merchantID AS text)) " +
            "AND (:statusIsNull or s.status IN (:status))", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Subscription> findWithStatus (@Param("merchantID")String merchantID, @Param("statusIsNull") Boolean statusIsNull, @Param("status") List<String> status);
```

So function call would be something like this:

```java
Boolean statusIsNull = (statusList == null || statusList.isEmpty()) ? true : false;

List<Subscription> subscriptionList = findWithStatus (merchantID, statusIsNull, statusList);
```

But I really recommend to use **JPA Criteria API** to build dynamic queries.

Regards.

Comment: you don't really need a seperate variable because you can make that choice in the query itself. Adapting ```"AND (:status is NULL or s.status IN (:status))", nativeQuery = true)``` to ```"AND (CASE WHEN :status is NULL THEN true ELSE s.status IN (:status) END;)", nativeQuery = true)```

Comment: Yes! both the solutions are working fine.

Comment: Thanks much for your time